# combining login from and pm system. can't check if user exists

Tags: php, mysql

the login is from http://www.php-login.net/ and the pm system is from http://www.webestools.com/scripts_tutorials-code-source-15-personal-message-system-in-php-mysql-pm-system-private-message-discussion.html.

my db tables are

```
--
-- Tabellenstruktur für Tabelle `pm`
--

CREATE TABLE `pm` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `user1` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `user2` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `user1read` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `user2read` varchar(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellenstruktur für Tabelle `users`
--

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'auto incrementing user_id of each user, unique index',
  `user_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s name',
  `user_password_hash` char(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s password in salted and hashed format',
  `user_email` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s email',
  `user_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'user''s activation status',
  `user_activation_hash` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'user''s email verification hash string',
  `user_password_reset_hash` char(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'user''s password reset code',
  `user_password_reset_timestamp` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'timestamp of the password reset request',
  `user_rememberme_token` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'user''s remember-me cookie token',
  `user_registration_datetime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `user_registration_ip` varchar(39) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_name` (`user_name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_email` (`user_email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='user data' AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

and the code i try to sent a message with is

```
    <?php
// include html header and display php-login message/error
include('header.php');

echo '<h2>New Personnal Message</h2>';
?>

<?php
//We check if the user is logged
if(isset($_SESSION['user_name']))
{
$form = true;
$otitle = '';
$orecip = '';
$omessage = '';
//We check if the form has been sent
if(isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['recip'], $_POST['message']))
{
    $otitle = $_POST['title'];
    $orecip = $_POST['recip'];
    $omessage = $_POST['message'];
    //We remove slashes depending on the configuration
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $otitle = stripslashes($otitle);
        $orecip = stripslashes($orecip);
        $omessage = stripslashes($omessage);
    }
    //We check if all the fields are filled
    if($_POST['title']!='' and $_POST['recip']!='' and $_POST['message']!='')
    {
        //We protect the variables
        $title = mysql_real_escape_string($otitle);
        $recip = mysql_real_escape_string($orecip);
        $message = mysql_real_escape_string(nl2br(htmlentities($omessage, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));
        //We check if the recipient exists
        $dn1 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select count(id) as recip, id as recipid, (select count(*) from pm) as npm from users where user_name="'.$recip.'"'));
        if($dn1['recip']==1)
        {
            //We check if the recipient is not the actual user
            if($dn1['recipid']!=$_SESSION['user_id'])
            {
                $id = $dn1['npm']+1;
                //We send the message
                if(mysql_query('insert into pm (id, id2, title, user1, user2, message, timestamp, user1read, user2read)values("'.$id.'", "1", "'.$title.'", "'.$_SESSION['user_id'].'", "'.$dn1['recipid'].'", "'.$message.'", "'.time().'", "yes", "no")'))
                {
?>
<div class="message">The message has successfully been sent.<br />
<a href="list_pm.php">List of my personnal messages</a></div>
<?php
                    $form = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Otherwise, we say that an error occured
                    $error = 'An error occurred while sending the message';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Otherwise, we say the user cannot send a message to himself
                $error = 'You cannot send a message to yourself.';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "$dn1";

            //Otherwise, we say the recipient does not exists
            $error = 'The recipient does not exists.';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Otherwise, we say a field is empty
        $error = 'A field is empty. Please fill of the fields.';
    }
}
elseif(isset($_GET['recip']))
{
    //We get the username for the recipient if available
    $orecip = $_GET['recip'];
}
if($form)
{
//We display a message if necessary
if(isset($error))
{
    echo '<div class="message">'.$error.'</div>';
}
//We display the form
?>
<div class="content">
    <form action="new_pm.php" method="post">
        Please fill the following form to send a personnal message.<br><br>
        <label for="recip">Recipient<span class="small">(Username)</span></label><input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($orecip, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" id="recip" name="recip" /><br />

        <label for="title">Title</label><input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($otitle, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" id="title" name="title" /><br />

        <label for="message">Message</label><textarea cols="40" rows="5" id="message" name="message"><?php echo htmlentities($omessage, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
</div>
<?php
}
}
else
{
    echo '<div class="message">You must be logged to access this page.</div>';
}
?>

<!-- backlink -->
<a href="index.php"><?php echo $phplogin_lang['Back to login']; ?></a>

<?php
// include html footer
include('footer.php');
```

i think the line thats not correct is:

```
$dn1 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select count(id) as recip, id as recipid, (select count(*) from pm) as npm from users where user_name="'.$recip.'"'));
```

but i dont get it

Comment: $error = 'The recipient does not exists.';

Comment: What does $dn1['recip'] contain?

Comment: when i try to echo this one it gives me an empty string

Comment: OK so please debug you mysql_functions. Make mysql_query to an own call like `$db_result = mysql_query("...") or die(mysql_error());` and then `$dn1 = mysql_fetch_array($db_result);`. Maybe then an error is printed out.

Comment: okay like you told me to. no it throws that error Access denied for user 'UNKNOWN_USER'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Okay, please post the part where you connect to the database with mysql_connect()

Comment: private function databaseConnection()
    {
        // connection already opened
        if ($this->db_connection != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            try {
                $this->db_connection = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
                return true;
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                $this->errors[] = $this->lang['Database error'] . $e->getMessage();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: You mix PDO with mysql. If you want to use mysql_query, then you have to use mysql_connect. Otherwise (which is better ;)) you have to change your query's etc to PDO format. They are not compatible.

Comment: also got that function

Comment: private function getUserData($user_name)
    {
        // if database connection opened
        if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
            // database query, getting all the info of the selected user
            $query_user = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = :user_name');
            $query_user->bindValue(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_user->execute();
            // get result row (as an object)
            return $query_user->fetchObject();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

Comment: So when you got functions written with PDO, why are you trying to use mysql_query and mysql_fetch_array()? Use PDO instead of these functions.

Comment: the login script im using ist pdo. the pm system isen't. i tried ($recip->isUserLoggedIn() == true);  but doesnt work

Comment: Well, if you want to use mysql then you must have somewhere a mysql_connect() function which starts a connection to the db for mysql_...() functions.

Comment: okay thank you i think i have to do some research

Comment: Sidenote: you shouldn't use mysql_* functions, because they are deprecated. Use mysqli_* ones instead!